# Python example of 3D bin packing problem and visualization

Tags: python, algorithm, optimization, gurobi, bin-packing

I am wondering if there are any python-based applications and examples about the 3D bin packing problem? I am facing a problem of planning the loading of thousands of items/boxes/pallets into the ocean containers (mainly 40HC).

Mannual planning, as most companies currently are doing, is very inefficient and painful. I am very interested to know if there is any python-based optimization toolkit that helps to solve such problem in a relatively accurate manner.

Allocating the items to containers are relatively easy, as I see from an example here: https://developers.google.com/optimization/bin/bin_packing#complete_programs
What is challenging is to generate a concrete plan telling people how to load each items into a specific container, like which box needs to be placed inside first, which item needs to be placed on top of others, so that the container storage space is maximally utilized.
And I hope to have a visual ouput like below. Are there any good coding examples?

[image]

[image]

Comment: There is lots of data out there about bin packing in 3D. Where exactly did you get stuck?

Comment: what do you mean. I simply need to find a good and accurate recommendation for boxes loading into the container. boxe size are various.

Comment: @Jack were you able to find something? Any advice would help! Thanks!

Comment: python 3DBP library. let me also know if you have other good alternatives :)

Answer (score 1):

I work on the Bin Packing problem and the only open-source python implementations that I have seen are those of academic research papers or heuristics. These have various limitations though such as not handling a large number of items or various physical constraints, and lacking a practical simulation guide for packing.

If you don't necessarily need access to the code, there is a growing number of  sophisticated software for your use case, such as [DeepPack](https://www.deeppack.ai/) by InstaDeep which is currently open for free access. It determines an optimal packing sequence using reinforcement learning, and shows a 3D simulation of the item packing order.